# Не срабатывает функция при нажатии кнопки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть примерно такая конструкция:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#panel').load('charmenu/panel.php');
    $("#b_c").click(function(){функция};
  });
```

В div с id=panel подгружается панель из трех кнопок, одна из которых имеет id=b_c. Функция, которая должна обрабатывать нажатие на эту кнопку, не срабатывает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный синтаксис в данном случае.

По голове сильно прошу не бить, только начал знакомство с jquery, в манах ничего не нашел

Comment: @Anansi

    $('#panel').on('click', '#b_c', function() {...});

Объяснять, как это работает, уже нету сил, если захотите разобраться - официальная документация по `.on()` и `google:delegated events` в помощь.